# SED to retain part of a file name in directory

Tags: sed, filenames, rename, bioinformatics

I have a `MainDirectory/hundreds_of_subdirectories/thousands_of_fastas` structure. For each fasta (a bioinformatics file format) in the bottom level, I am trying to change the file name as well as the first line in the file to retain only some parts of the file.

So that the following text, which makes up both the file name and the first name of the file:

```
947-length-1150-cov-1000|contig:JAECWU010000213.1|slice:817050-818200|uce:uce-1452|match:817550-817700|orient:{'+'}|probes:4.unaligned.fasta
```

becomes just:

```
uce-1452.unaligned.fasta
```

For editing the first line in the file, I have tried

```bsh
sed '1 s/^[^|uce-]*(|uce-[0-9]).*/\1/' hundreds_of_subdirectories/*
```

but this isn't the ticket..

Then messing around with some kind of loop...

```bsh
for i in *\*.unaligned.fasta; do sed -E 's/^[^|uce-]*(|uce-[0-9]).*/\1/'; done
```

For the file name, it was suggested that I use `rename` instead of `sed`, but with `sed` I have tried something like:

```bsh
for x in hundreds_of_subdirectories/thousands_of_fastas*unaligned.fasta; do
    echo $x | sed -r 's/^[^|uce-]*(|uce-[0-9]).*/mv' -v "\0" "|uce-[0-9].*/\1/.unaligned.fasta"/
done
```

Am I even barking up the right tree? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to rename files, then the tool that you want is `rename`. `sed` is for editing the contents of files or standard output.

Comment: If there all named with the same layout as your example this will work `cut -d':' -f 4 | sed 's/|match/.unaligned.fasta/'`

Comment: Hi @JasonCroyle, thanks! Can you elaborate a bit more? I tried this in a subdirectory, but it did not do anything...  ` for i in *\*.unaligned.fasta; do cut -d':' -f 4 | sed 's/|match/.unaligned.fasta/ ; done `

Answer (score 2):

Using `find` and the Perl `rename` utility, you could use

```
find MainDirectory -type f -name '*.unaligned.fasta' \
  -exec rename -v -d 's/.*:(uce-\d+).*/$1.unaligned.fasta/' {} +
```

This only changes the filename part of each path (option `-d`) and leaves the filename unchanged if the destination filename already exists. Remove option `-v` for non-verbose output.

Comment: Thank you, Freddy, I tried the following: 'find /Users/Malia/Downloads/exploded_fastas/chymomyza_mxostata_exploded_fastas -type f -name '*.unaligned.fasta' \
  -exec rename -v -d 's/.*:(uce-\d+).*/$1.unaligned.fasta/' {} +' but it does not appear to make changes...anything glaringly wrong to your eyes?